# Unpack a rar file

Tags: vb.net, unpack, unrar

Okay, so I have searched for dll files that will allow me to unrar files and I was able to find quite a few such as unrar.dll, chilkat, sharpcompress and some more but I wanted to use the one provided by Rar themselves.

So I referenced the DLL file in my project and imported it. I was using unrar.dll.

But I wasn't able to find any up to date code to allow me to test and try things out. All the examples I found were either not up to date or not for Vb.net.

I also tried the official example, which came in the installation but that didn't work even after I fixed it and when I tried to use the code I always got an error for

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I just want to unrar a rar file from a specific location to the root directory of my program so if my program was on the desktop I want it to unrar a file in My documents and extract the files to my desktop.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the code you tried that threw the error you are asking about?

Comment: It was the default code. It would be too long to type it here, but here is the link to the official RAR website where you can get it from: http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm

Comment: This site doesn't allow questions asking for references or libraries, and your programming question is too broad. Try to reduce your question to a specific programming problem in which we can help you with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to unrar files, I Was able to do that with [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)

First I created a new VB.Net App and added a reference to SharpCompress.dll before using this code to extract all the files from a Rar file.

```
'Imports 
Imports SharpCompress.Archives
Imports SharpCompress.Common

'Unrar code
Dim archive As IArchive = ArchiveFactory.Open("C:\file.rar")

For Each entry In archive.Entries
    If Not entry.IsDirectory Then
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key)
        entry.WriteToDirectory("C:\unrar", New ExtractionOptions With  
                              {.ExtractFullPath = True, .Overwrite = True})
    End If
Next
```

[More code samples](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Composite%20API%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick. I looked at that page but the code seem outdated. I'll have another look. Again thanks, I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

for those who will try in vb.net the extract options are renamed and used as

```
Dim options As New ExtractionOptions With {
    .ExtractFullPath = True,
    .Overwrite = True
}
entry.WriteToDirectory(Application.StartupPath, options)
```