# Extract file using SevenZip

Tags: vb.net, sevenzipsharp

I'm trying to add a file unzipper to my application, so I googled a little and stumbled on the [sevenzipsharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com) library that is able to extract the most common archive formats.

So I for testing I created a simple application with a windows form.

[image: Form screenshot]

So the entered data is the file location `C:\Users\jeee\Desktop\CriticalSubPrintout.rar` and the extract location `C:\Users\jeee\Desktop\Test Extract`

I added some code, without any documentation.. not my strong side apparently..

```
Imports SevenZip

Public Class Archiver

    Private Sub btnExtractArchive_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExtractArchive.Click

        Dim Extractor As New SevenZipExtractor(tbExtractFile.Text)
        Extractor.ExtractArchive(tbExtractPath.Text)

    End Sub

End Class
```

This causes an error when I try and run the code

[image: Error Image]

Can anyone provide a sample code, or a link to a good example how-to-use `SevenZipSharp`? Because I searched and can't find any `VB.NET` samples.

Or maybe just help me figure out what I need to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Personally wouldn't use SevenZipSharp, maybe try this?: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257193/Easily-zip-unzip-files-using-Windows-Shell32

Comment: Why? Please explain. And does the method in the link also support .RAR files?

Comment: I've personally found SevenZipSharp a bit unreliable with documentation. Here is a previous question asking about .RAR files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522605/unpack-a-rar-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath` with the path to 7z.dll, and make sure that you are using the correct version for your application (32- or 64-bit).  e.g.

```
SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath("C:\Dev\7z.dll")
Dim Extractor As New SevenZipExtractor(tbExtractFile.Text)
Extractor.ExtractArchive(tbExtractPath.Text)
```